# Cucumber with Kotlin: Problems with duplicate step definitions

Tags: kotlin, cucumber

I've gotten the "duplicate step definitions" after converting som Java step definitions to Kotlin. Jenkins identifies the following step defintions as duplicates:

```
@Given("^that \"([^\"]*)\" is a case in city \"([^\"]*)\" to buy a specific house with code$")
fun theCaseIsACaseInCityToBuySpecificHouseWithCode(caseTag: String, city: String) {

@Given("^that \"([^\"]*)\" is a case in city \"([^\"]*)\" to buy a specific house$")
fun theCaseIsACaseInCityToBuySpecificHouse(caseTag: String = "case", city: String = "5035") {
```

The error message by Jenkins claims:

```
cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException:
Duplicate step definitions in void e2e.case.CreateCaseSteps
.theCaseIsACaseInCityToBuySpecificHouse(String,String)
in file:/tmp/workspace/EST_cases_PR-12432/e2e/cucumber/target/test-classes/
and
e2e.case.CreateCaseSteps.theCaseIsACaseInCityToBuySpecificHouse
$default(OpprettSakSteps,String,String,int,Object)
```

I've seen similar with Java too, but I seem to rememeber the problem being the last "$" missing, so that the second line would "equal" the first.

With this in Kotlin, the problem seems to be something else.

Any ideas? There doesn't seem to be much info about Cucumber and Kotlin around.

Comment: You might still have java classes with test methods that share the same name as the kotlin test methods

Comment: I might have had, but I don't. I've been carefully moving one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently allmost no one uses kotlin and cucumber, I'll share what I've found myself after testing and testing and testing:

**Cucumber cannot handle step definitions with default parameter values**

I know cucumber isn't able to utilize default parameter values, but I didn't think just having them there would result in a seemingly completely bogus error (duplicate step definition). However, it does. I had a couple of step definition methods that were also used by other step definition methods. And for those, having default paramter values made sense and created more tidy code. But, alas, it doesn't work when Cucumber is involved.